# Is there any Windows screen recorder that works with multiple virtual desktops?

Tags: windows, virtual-desktop, screen-recorder

I'd like to record a virtual desktop screen while working on another one. Is there a video recorder which would support such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I am aware of, since pretty much all virtual desktop programs just "hide" windows to simulate a virtual desktop.

You should try the System Internals Virtual Desktop and see if a screen recorder will work there. . .

Comment: thanks for suggestion, tried with screenr screen goes black when desktop not active. But good utility I discovered though :)

Comment: I didn't even mention other caveats, like most applications don't update their window at all if they do not receive draw events from Windows, which is the case when the window is hidden.